# Como atribuir valores a uma quantidade indefinida de variáveis em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variáveis

Para atribuir valores a múltiplas variáveis é só seguir essa estrutura: a, b, c = 1, 2, 3; Isso eu sei, mas e se por exemplo eu quiser armazenar vários valores que vieram de um input sem saber a quantidade de valores? Como que eu faço isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em geral, se você não tem exatamente um valor pra cada variável, ou seja, se as variáveis vão ter a mesma funcionalidade e guardar elementos de uma sequência, então o melhor é fazer isso: guardar os valores direto numa sequência - em geral, uma lista.

Então, vamos supor que você faça um input, siga com um split, e, então, tendo uma sequência sem tamanho conhecido no momento da programação queira atribuir isso a uma variável: não precisa fazer mais nada, por que o conteúdo já é uma lista - e a lista já é o valor devolvido pelo valor do split.

Vou seguir com exemplos no prompt interativo (o prompt tem `In[XX]` em vez do tradicional `>>>` por que é um shell do iPython - a linguagem usada é exatamente o mesmo Python do shell normal):

```
In [83]: entrada = input("Entre com valores separados por espaço: ").split()                             
Entre com valores separados por espaço: teste de entrada de várias palavras

In [84]: print(entrada)                                                                                  
['teste', 'de', 'entrada', 'de', 'várias', 'palavras']
```

Então, como eu disse, se cada valor digitado vai ser usado da mesma forma, então o mais simples é eu manter a variável `entrada`. Um `for` vai processar palavra por palavra dessa lista, de forma bem mais simples do que se estivesse cada palavra numa variável diferente - basta fazer `for palavra in entrada:`.

Agora, vamos supor que as entradas não sejam todas iguais, e que a primeira e segunda palavras tenham uma função específica, e, eu não me importe com as outras - nesse caso, sim, a distribuição de atribuição do Python permite que seja usado um `*` como prefixo para indicar que naquela variável vai uma lista com "tudo o que sobrou". Continuando o exemplo anterior:

```
In [91]: a, b, *c = entrada                                                                              

In [92]: print (f"a: {a}, b: {b}, c: {c}")                                                               
a: teste, b: de, c: ['entrada', 'de', 'várias', 'palavras']
```

Note que o `*` não precisa ser usado na última variável - se as que eu quero separar são a primeira e a última palavras, por exemplo, e quero manter todas as outras numa lista, posso fazer:

```
In [93]: a, *b, c = entrada                                                                              

In [94]: print (f"a: {a}, b: {b}, c: {c}")                                                               
a: teste, b: ['de', 'entrada', 'de', 'várias'], c: palavras
```

Se existe um número *máximo* de itens na sua entrada, mas ela pode opcionalmente ser menor, tem como dar um jeito: criamos um iterador que preencha os itens faltantes com um valor "em branco" como `None`. Há várias formas de fazer isso - e podemos usar uma list comprehension com um `if` ternário para nossos efeitos.  **Importante** de perceber aqui, é que as ressalvas para criar as variáveis dinâmicas ja começam a se aplicar, e o código começa a ficar complexo, principalmente para quem não conhecer bem a linguagem:

```
In [101]: a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = [entrada[i] if i < len(entrada) else None for i in range(8)]          

In [102]: print(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h)                                                                  
teste de entrada de várias palavras None None
```

## Ok, mas eu *quero* criar uma variável para cada item da entrada sem saber o tamanho

Até aqui faz parte da sintaxe normal do Python, apenas são um aspectos mais avançados dela. Especificamente o que você quer pode ser feito de outra forma - usando as capacidades do Python de introspecção e dinamismo, que permitem a alteração dinâmica de variáveis pelo próprio programa que está sendo executado.

Não é difícil fazer isso - mas, pelo motivo que citei primeiro nessa resposta, não faz sentido - já que, se você for criar uma variável dinamicamente, não vai poder escrever nenhum código que *use* essa variável por nome mais pra frente, já que não sabe se ela vai existir. Então faz mais sentido manter a sequência como uma lista, ou até colocar a sequência num dicionário se for apropriado.

Mas para fins de exemplo, o que se pode usar nesse caso é o fato de a chamada a função `globals()` do Python devolver um dicionário com as variáveis globais do módulo atual. Se usarmos ele como um dicionário comum, as entradas criadas nesse dicionário são criadas "de verdade" como variáveis globais. Isso é possível por que ao manipular o dicionário, os nomes das variáveis são strings - e strings são dados que podemos manipular com as várias funções do Python. Só  que - insisto - isso não teria uso num programa normal.

O trecho abaixo cria as variáveis, começando em `a0` e incrementando o dígito  para cada palavra da sequência:

```
In [97]: for i, palavra in enumerate(entrada): 
    ...:     globals()['a' + str(i)] = palavra 
    ...:      
    ...:                                                                                                 

In [98]: print(a0, a1, a2, a3, a4)                                                                       
teste de entrada de várias

In [99]: print(a5)                                                                                       
palavras

In [100]: print(a6)                                                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-ff75f4805c17> in <module>
----> 1 print(a6)

NameError: name 'a6' is not defined
```

Deixei o erro estourar de propósito - se fosse um programa, e não um exemplo no modo interativo, o código pra baixo da criação das variáveis não teria como saber quais dessas variáveis `aN` teriam sido criadas - a única forma de usar alguma seria colocando o seu uso dentro de um `try...except NameError: ...` - o que se sobrepõe a qualquer utilidade que isso poderia ter. E mesmo que fosse simples usar esses nomes no programa, perceba que o programa fica maior e você tem que digitar muito mais do que precisaria se cada elemento estivesse dentro de uma lista. Esse exemplo ainda permite ver ao mesmo tempo o uso prático para a `entrada` como uma lista: ela é usada diretamente no `for`. (nesse caso usei junto com a função `enumerate` para criar um índice numérico para cada palavra)

Note, no entando, que essa solução não funciona para variáveis locais - apenas globais. Isso por que alterações feitas no dicionário retornado por `locals()` não alteram as variáveis locais: o acesso as mesmas é otimizado internamente, e não passa por esse dicionário - ele é útil apenas para leitura.

Comment: PS. a resposta do @maniero estaria de bom tamanho - você *não deve* fazer isso num programa. Acrescentei essa resposta mais para mostrar as sintaxes com `*` do que para colocar o exmplo "do que não fazer". Mas esse exemplo ajuda a entender melhor a linguagem, então ele fica ai.

Comment: Beleza, obrigado. Ajudou muito.

Answer (score 1):

De forma direta não é possível. Dá para criar uma algoritmo sofisticado que gerencie isto. E aí depende do que chama de variável. Embora seja possível criar variáveis em tempo de execução, quase sempre isto é um código ruim e errado.

A não ser que esteja se referindo a variáveis cada elemento de uma lista, o que é algo até correto, aí se torna mais simples, e provavelmente correto. Se você não sabe quantos elementos precisa a lista resolve bem porque ela tem a quantidade indefinida mesmo, a execução é que determinará seu tamanho.

Eu aconselharia usar a lista como um *array*, portanto os elementos são referenciados por um índice numérico sequencial sem intervalos. Mas usar uma chave específica em um dicionário pode ser uma solução também.

Claro que em qualquer caso seu código deverá tratar disto de forma adequada para identificar quantos valores são e colocar em cada variável, mas a solução é o *array*.  Uma forma de *array* é sempre a solução para essas coisas. É uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) que resolve o indeterminismo do problema.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Comment: E se eu colocar um limite? Por exemplo sei que a entrada terá entre 1 e 1000 elementos. Como posso fazer isso? Por exemplo um calculador de média, pode ser dado dois números, 3, 4, 10, 20 e etc para que se faça a média aritmética entre eles. Quero saber apenas a parte que se pega os valores do input e os armazena em variáveis: num1, num2, num3...

Comment: Não, acabei de falar que não pode fazer isso, é inviável, faz a lista e resolve seu problema.

Comment: Beleza, agora entendi. Obrigado.

Comment: Nem dá pra calcular a média criando uma variável nova pra cada dado, por que você não vai saber quantos dados foram criados - daí soma todos os valores, e divide por quanto?? 

Já, se tiver numa lista de nome `valores` a média é simplesmente: `media = sum(valores) / len(valores)`